# AWS S3 pre signed url - download file getting 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 2 buckets
in the first bucket when I am uploading a file and adding pre signed url for download
all is fine
how ever in the second bucket when I try to download the file , I am getting 403
both buckets have the same configuration. I have tried using AWS Java SDK and AWS cli, same results. The only difference in buckets is that in the one that isnt working, it was created one month after the one that is working

Comment: Does your service that issues the presigned urls have proper access to both buckets?

Comment: yes
i have tried using my admin keys

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, when i had `Bucket A` and I was getting `403` on every operation on the bucket (`download`, `open` via the AWS console etc..)

The issue was, the role used to `putObject` (`Role A`) on the bucket **wasn't** in the same account as the role(`Role B`) used to `view` / `download` the file

**FIX**: when `putObject` with `Role A`, I had to add `acl` config with `bucket-owner-read` so `Role B` which is also the bucket owner, can `view`/`get` the object